# User control responds to event from page it's added to

Tags: c#, button, user-controls

I have a usercontrol page which has a label on it and the `onLoad` code for the label is written in C#.  The page I added the usercontrol to has a button.  Is there any way for me to code the usercontrol so that it changes the label in response to the button press?  Preferably this would be done from the usercontrol page in C#.  I'm not sure if it would affect anything about this but the non-usercontrol page has the code behind done in VB.

Thanks for any insight on this.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Mostly I've been looking online for information on it.  I was gonna add a Button_click method to the user control but don't know if you can make it reference the parent page button or how to do it if you can.  Most of the stuff I'm finding online is about the opposite direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code for your Page.aspx add a declarative event handler for the button click and add the following code within it alongside the other logic-

C#

```
Protected void Button_OnClick(object sender, eventargs e)
{
   //Other logic responding to the click event within the page
   LabelUserControl.PageButton_Click(sender, e); 
}
```

VB.NET

```
Protected Sub PageButton_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PageButton.Click 
   LabelUserControl.PageButton_Click(sender, e)
End Sub
```

or (if the user control label change is the only response to the click)-

C#

```
Protected void Page_Load(object sender, eventargs e)
{
   PageButton.Click += LabelUserControl.PageButton_Click;
}
```

VB.NET

```
Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler PageButton.Click, AddressOf LabelUserControl.PageButton_Click
End Sub
```

In your user control-

```
public void PageButton_Click(object sender, eventargs e)
{
  // change label text
}
```

The method should be public so it can be accessed from the page.

Comment: To clarify the first part is in Page.aspx or in page.aspx.vb?  If it goes in the codefile will the fact that the codefile is in VB prevent it from getting the c# method in the user control to work?

Comment: Sorry, I had probably opened the question before your edit as I don't remember the part about VB.NET, if it was already there I apologise for missing it.

Comment: The above code is all C# and should either be in the code behind (if there is one) or contained within <script runat="server"> //code here </script> tags in the page/usercontrol if not. Although I haven't experience of working between C# and VB.NET in this way both the sender (button) object and eventargs will be defined in the Base Class Library so it should be possible to pass them between languages without any problems. All code above is in C# syntax so the page code will be to be updated to VB.NET syntax. I assume (but don't know for sure) that events are managed in the same way.

Comment: I've tried converting the first bit of code to vb and it's giving me a PageButton_Click is not a member of System.web.UI.UserControl error.  This error is from when I try to use userControl.PageButton_Click.  If you have a solution for this I'd like to hear it in the mean time I'll look online

Comment: I have edited the answer with what I hope is the correct VB.NET code to allow you to do what you want to do, that has been a learning experience for me, and added a name for the UserControl to make the answer clearer. The code does work in a sample website I created to test it.

Comment: For complete clarity, the PageButton_Click needs to be referenced from the instance of your user control, not the generic UserControl class.

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience.  This is gonna sound stupid because but when you say referenced from the instance of user control you mean what? I'm sure it'll be obvious once I have it explained a bit more but right now I'm not sure what you mean.  I currently have the PageButton_Click in the code I get to by double clicking the user control from the aspx view designer.  Does it need to be somewhere else?

Comment: When you add a user control reference to a page you are creating an *instance* of a *class* you have created when you added the user control to the project. This will inherit from the generic UserControl class but add properties and methods. The generic UserControl class has no method PageButton_Click, we created that method in our own custom class. To subscribe the *method* PageButton_Click to the click *event* of the button you must reference an instance of the custom class - for example the usercontrol object you referenced and placed on the page - and not the base UserControl class.

Comment: If you already have the click event handler in code you should just need to paste in- LabelUserControl.PageButton_Click(sender, e) - where LabelUserControl is the ID of the C# user control you have added to the page and it contains a public method named PageButton_Click accepting an object and EventArgs as arguments. If this answer and the comments help you please consider accepting.